# Is receiving commission on purchase haram?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work

I am working as a purchaser in a company. When I make purchases, I always bargain with suppliers to get lowest rate and give orders to suppliers who offer low rate. After the purchase, when company give cheque, he offers a commission to me based on quantity purchased.  The supplier's price is fixed and they will not reduce the price even I am not accepting the commission.  Is it haram or halal?

Comment: Isn's this just a reward for you work?

Answer (score 0):

The way kickbacks work is this way:

- Company gives you a price
- Company pays you after you complete the sale

Now, imagine there is another company that will give you the items 5% less cost, but they won't give kickbacks. Most employees will stick with the expensive company so they get their additional kickbacks.

This is highly [illegal](http://www.mcgoverngreene.com/archives/archive_articles/Craig_Greene_Archives/bribery-kickbacks-payoffs.html) in the US and many countries and can lead you to serious trouble. In many companies, including my own, it is not allowed and if you get let's say a box of chocolate or a gift it is to be shared with everyone in the company.

Now, since this is illegal, it makes it automatically haram unless of course you have an agreement with the company owner you are working for.

Answer (score -1):

That commission is illegal,  or haraam if i may use Islamic term. If you had stayed in your house or the house of your mother, not working for the company,  would the supplier look for you and give you the commission. The answer is NO.If they insist you take commission, then take it to the company/employer to decide what to be done with it.This type of practice has destroyed many countries in Africa and Asia-unfortunately this type of corruption is very rampant in many Muslim being one of the key the driver of inequality, retardation, injustice, instability and conflicts.   Response from another reader indicated it is strictly prohibited in the US- may be that is way US is strong country.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.